# C - How to move a number to a different place in a matrix

Tags: c, arrays, function, matrix

this is what i've written

```
int n=0,i=0,j=0,k=0,s=0,a=0,b=0;
int blk[n][n];

printf("how many blocks?\n");
scanf ("%d", &n);
printf("\n");

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    blk[i][j]=k;
    printf("%d: %d\t  ",k, blk[i][j]);
    k++;
    printf("\n");
}
```

it is supposed to look like this

0:0

1:1

2:2

...

8:8

9:9

the user then has a set of commands that move the numbers in different ways trough functions
my problem is i don't know how to make the numbers move to look like this for example

0:0

1:1 9

2:2

...

8:8

9:

the first comand puts "a" on top of b" (so 9 on top of 1)

the first numbers are the positions (#:), the numbers in front is where the matrix starts

Comment: This doesn't look like nxn matrix.

Comment: `int blocks[n][n];` `n` is zero here.

Comment: the spaces are supposed to be empty so u can add numbers, you could put all of the numbers bellow in front of the first one for example, and complete the entire line if that makes sence

Comment: `blocks[1][1] = 9;`. But what do you put at `blocks[9][0]` to mark it as empty?

Comment: variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)  Names like: `n,i,j,k,s,a,b` are meaningless, even int current context.

Comment: regarding: `int n=0,i=0,j=0,k=0,s=0,a=0,b=0;
int blocks[n][n];`  this results in an array defined as `blocks[0][0]`  which will not get any bigger when the value in `n` is increased,  Strongly suggest Do not declare the array `blocks[][]` until after the value of `n` has been read from the user.  (note that makes use of the `VLA` feature of C

Answer (score 3):

You should've declared the blocks variable after you read `n` like so.

Also you forgot the second for loop.

```
int n=0,i=0,j=0,k=0,s=0,a=0,b=0;

printf("Enter the numember of blocks desired\n");
scanf ("%d", &n);
printf("\n");

int blocks[n][n];

for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
        blocks[i][j]=k;
        printf("%d: %d\t  ",k, blocks[i][j]);
        k++;
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: @gsamaras The question as I understand it is that the author doesn't get the expected output. This is a solution to contribute to the correct output.

Comment: After re-reading, I don't think OP wants a nested loop. They just want the first column of each row filled in. I could be wrong. The question is unclear.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp agree, the question is unclear. What are the a and b commands? what is the specification for "moving" things around in the matrix? Given the code snippet, I believe this solution somewhat helps the author better understand what they want

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are describing an NxN matrix.  For N == 10, and initialized to zeros, it could conceptually look like this:

[image]

Then you describe you would like to move a number around.  For example, place a value into a particular location, such as place a 55 into `matrix[3][3]`.  Keeping in mind a zero based index system, the matrix would now look like:

[image]

Steps that might be implemented to do this:

***Steps:***
0) call program with command line value for order of matrix.
1) create nxn table using value entered on command line.
2) prompt user to enter where, and what value to place, or quit.
3) clear previous contents.
4) place new value.
5) go to step 2.

Implementation example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    int value = 0;
    if(argc != 2) 
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <integer value for order>\n Exiting", argv[0]);
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
    int order = atoi(argv[1]);

    int matrix[order][order];

    int exit = 'x';

    while(exit != 'q')
    {
        printf("Enter 3 space delimited digits with values from 0 to %d.\n\n", order-1);
        scanf(" %d %d %d", &x, &y, &value);
        memset(matrix, 0, x*y*sizeof(int));
        matrix[x][y] = value;
        for(int i=0;i<order;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<order;j++)
            {
                if((i==x) && (j==y)) 
                {
                    printf("%3d", value);
                    if(j == order-1)printf("\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%3d", 0);
                    if(j == order-1)printf("\n");
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\nHit 'q' to quit, any other key to continue");
        exit = getchar();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

For an `order == 10` matrix, tested for the following `x`, `y` and `value` command line entries:

`0 0 99`, `0 9 99`, `9 0 99`, `9 9 99`

[image]